# Returning both a table and a scalar from a stored procedure in MSSQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to return both table data AND a count of the table data through an OUT parameter from a SP. The count isn't of the table data in it's final state, rather it's the table data pre doing TOP 100 to return just 100 rows. I think the following does what I want, but is there a more efficient way to achieve this?

```
    CREATE PROC sp_total_recs
        @total_recs INT OUT
    AS
    BEGIN
        -- return top 100 records only
        SELECT TOP 100 *
        INTO #temp
        FROM
        (
        SELECT *, COUNT(1) OVER () AS total_records
        FROM table
        ) T;

        SET @total_recs = (SELECT DISTINCT total_records FROM #temp);

        SELECT *
        FROM #temp;

        DROP TABLE #temp;

        RETURN
    END;


    DECLARE @tot_recs INT;
    EXEC sp_total_recs
        @total_recs = @tot_recs OUTPUT;
```

Comment: What are you returning it to? Just in SSMS? Can you show your expected output?

Comment: Slight detour...you should consider not using the sp_ prefix (or even better, no prefix at all). That prefix is reserved by MS and can cause performance issues in addition to some other really fun issues. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix And when using TOP you should also use ORDER BY or you have now of ensuring which rows will be returned.

Comment: @SeanLange Slightly more detour :-) Even with `ORDER BY` you might get unexpected (or better: unpredictable) rows, if you don't add `WITH TIES` (exception: UNIQUE value to sort by) `</weisenheimer>` :-)

Comment: @Shnugo good point. :)

Comment: In my eyes this is a wrong approach... Why not use an *inline table valued function* instead of your SP? The calling side would easily get the count directly...

Comment: @WEI_DATA - returning to a C# front end which I've no real visibility over but I'm reliably informed the C# can access the table returned in the above SP as well as the output params.

Comment: @SeanLange - ignore the TOP bit, will define that better at some point in the future :) for now this is more about the most efficient way to return both a table and some output scalar params.

Comment: I agree with @Shnugo. Returning the data AND a count is kind of silly. Just return the table. Not sure how your c# is retrieving this information but nearly every object you would pull this in to has a count property that will get the number of rows.